# Async Event Subscription

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, event-driven

I am using a third party API and it looks like its written using Event Driven Architecture. I am making an asynchronous call to one of the methods on the API but the response from the method is returned in the event handler only. Hence I have to subscribe to the event and then invoke the method call to the API.

Pseudo-code Example:

```
private string myValue;

public async Task<string> TestPost()
{
    // Subscribe to event
    api.OnSomeAPIFunctionResponse += EventHandler1;

    await CallAPIFunction(...with some parameters...);

    return myValue;
}

private void EventHandler1(sender, args)
{
    // This is the value I want to return in the previous function
    myValue = args.value;
}
```

In the code example above myValue is null when I run the application because the event handler code kicks in after the function has returned execution.

How can I make the event handler execute asynchronously before the TestPost function returns.

Please suggest me what can be done here.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to do? You can get the correct value of `MYVALUE` by calling `TestPost.Wait()` but that is a blocking operation and calling it form a UI thread may cause a deadlock.

If you are trying to set a value to the result of the function, it may be better to `await` its result

```
var myVar = await TestPost();
```

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_AsyncandAwait) explains a bit more about `async/await`

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, you can use a `TaskCompletionSource` to achieve what you want. This is untested code, but maybe something like this:

```
    public Task<string> TestPost()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
      // Subscribe to event
      api.OnSomeAPIFunctionResponse += ( (s, e) => tcs.SetResult(args.value));

      CallAPIFunction(...with some parameters....);
      return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Then you get the result the same way:

```
var myVar = await TestPost();
```

`TaskCompletionSource` allows you to convert older asynchronous APIs to use the task based asynchronous pattern. This in turn allows you to use the functionality provided by the Task Parallel Library and also use the new keywords in .NET 4.5 `async` and `await`. It results in much simpler code. You can read more about `TaskCompletionSource` in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx) by Stephen Toub from the Parallel .NET Team

Comment: Thanks but please read the post I have said the event that I am subscribed to returns the result and not the actual function which has await on it. I want to run the event and the event handler both simultaneously so when the TestPost function returns it has a value from the event handler argument. Thanks :)